# SSH login with bash and expect

Tags: bash, expect

I have to ssh into numerous devices daily, over and over...
I can automate it with bash & expect with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn  ssh hostname -l username
expect "password:"
send "secret\n"
interact
```

The majority of the devices require 'root' as the login, so the above script works well for that. I'd like to modify the above script to attempt to login once, and if it fails, to switch to another username and prompt me for the password. Is that possible?

I know about keys, and the bad practice of passwords in scripts, it isn't important in my case.

Comment: If you know about keys, then use them.

Comment: Using expect to automate ssh works but it is very rudimentary. Nowadays there are easy to use modules for almost any scripting languages (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.) that will allow you to perform that tasks with far less work.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) has tons of great examples.

```
expect {
  "string that indicates success" {
  }
  "string that indicates failure" {
    close
    stty -echo
    send_user "Enter password: "
    expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
    send_user "\n"
    send "$expect_out(1,string)\r"
    stty echo
  }
}
interact
```